# Merging 3 tables and searching by the last

Tags: filtering, jhipster

I have a Property entity that has the id for a City entity.
The City entity that has the id for a State entity.
And the State entity that has the id for a Country entity.

I need to find all propreties in a country.

My solution is this one:

```
protected Specification<Property> createSpecification(PropertyCriteria criteria) {
    ...
    if (criteria.getCountryId() != null) {
            StateCriteria stateCriteria = new StateCriteria();
            stateCriteria.setCountryId(criteria.getCountryId());
            List<StateDTO> states = stateQueryService.findByCriteria(stateCriteria);
            List<Long> statesIds = states.stream().map(StateDTO::getId).collect(Collectors.toList());

            LongFilter statesInCountry = new LongFilter();
            statesInCountry.setIn(statesIds);

            CityCriteria cityCriteria = new CityCriteria();
            cityCriteria.setStateId(statesInCountry);
            List<CityDTO> cities = cityQueryService.findByCriteria(cityCriteria);
            List<Long> citiesId = cities.stream().map(CityDTO::getId).collect(Collectors.toList());

            LongFilter citiesInState = new LongFilter();
            citiesInState.setIn(citiesId);

            specification = specification.and(buildSpecification(citiesInState,
                root -> root.join(Property_.city, JoinType.LEFT).get(City_.id)));
    }
    ...
}
```

Is there a better solution using `buildSpecification()`? I find really difficult to understand what the inhered functions from `QueryService` actually do because of the type parametrization.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all the `Property` in a `Country` you should join the entities and apply the filter to the country ID.

```java
protected Specification<Property> createSpecification(PropertyCriteria criteria) {
    ...
    if (criteria.getCountryId() != null) {
        specification = specification.and(buildSpecification(criteria.getCountryId(),
            root -> root.join(Property_.city, JoinType.LEFT)
                        .join(City_.state, JoinType.LEFT)
                        .join(State_.country, JoinType.LEFT)
                        .get(Country_.id)));
    }
    ...
}
```

See if this does what you need.